# Not able to execute go file using os/exec package

Tags: go

I am following the [golang tutorial](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) for writing my web app. I am modifying the code from [tutorial page](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/), so that I can execute the saved page as go code (similar to [go playground](https://play.golang.org/)). But when I try to execute the saved go file using the `os/exec` package, it throws the following error.

> exec: "go run testcode.go": executable file not found in $PATH

Following is my modified code :

```
// Structure to hold the Page
type Page struct {
    Title  string
    Body   []byte
    Output []byte
}

// saving the page
func (p *Page) save() { // difference between func (p *Page) and func (p Page)
    filename := p.Title + ".go"
    ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0777)
}

// handle for the editing
func editHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := r.URL.Path[len("/edit/"):]

    p, err := loadPage(title)

    if err != nil {
        p = &Page{Title: title}
    }
    htmlTemp, _ := template.ParseFiles("edit.html")
    htmlTemp.Execute(w, p)
}

// saving the page
func saveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    title := r.URL.Path[len("/save/"):]
    body := r.FormValue("body")

    p := Page{Title: title, Body: []byte(body)}
    p.save()

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/exec/"+title, http.StatusFound) // what is statusfound
}

// this function will execute the code.
func executeCode(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    title := r.URL.Path[len("/exec/"):]

    cmd := "go run " + title + ".go"
    //cmd = "go"
    fmt.Print(cmd)
    out, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("could not execute")
        fmt.Fprint(w, err)
    } else {
        p := Page{Title: title, Output: out}

        htmlTemp, _ := template.ParseFiles("output.html")
        htmlTemp.Execute(w, p)
    }
}
```

Please tell me why I am not able to able to execute the go file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are invoking command in the wrong way. The first string is the full path to the executable

[os.exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command):`func Command(name string, arg ...string)`

so you want `exec.Command("/usr/bin/go", "run", title+".go")`

Comment: Yes, now error has changed to `fork/exec /usr/local/go/bin/go run ABSOLUTE_PATH/testcode.go: no such file or directory`. Go file is created and visible in directory, I am able to run the program (testcode.go) from the terminal as well.

Comment: from terminal with those exact strings ? go to the / root directory and try to execute your file from there

Comment: Yes using the `/usr/local/go/bin/go run ABSOLUTE_PATH/testcode.go` from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer states that the first argument to [os.exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) is the full path to the executable. From the docs:

"If name contains no path separators, **Command uses LookPath** to resolve the path to a complete name if possible. Otherwise it uses name directly".

What you should do to avoid `executable file not found in $PATH` errors, besides passing the arguments after the executable name as suggested before, is to set your `PATH` either in your SHELL or using [os.Setenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Setenv). If you hardcode the full location of the command like indicated, your program might not be portable to another Unix OS.

For example, the command `lspci` is located under `/usr/bin` in ubuntu and under `/sbin/` in RHEL. If you do this:

```
os.Setenv("PATH", "/usr/bin:/sbin")
exec.Command("lspci", "-mm")
```

Then your program will excecute in both ubuntu and RHEL.

Or, form the shell, you can also do: `PATH=/sbin; my_program`

NOTE: The commands above are limiting the `PATH` to the explicitly indicated paths. If you want to add to the existing path in the shell for example, do `PATH=/sbin:$PATH; my_program`; In go you can probably read the variable with `os.Getenv` and then append to that when doing `os.Setenv`.

Comment: The accepted answer **is** correct. The issue the OP had was they rammed an entire multi-argument command line into the first argument as the executable file name to find run which is exactly what the accept answer pointed out and corrected. The only nit with the answer is that they did not need to use the full path to go (they should probably just assume it's on the path; you *really* don't want to mess with the `PATH` environment variable like you suggest).

Comment: If you are running scripts as root, it is important to limit the `PATH` to avoid security concerns.  I edited my answer to acknowledge what you brought up.

Comment: Yes but your executable should **not** be mucking with the path. The OP was executing `go`, you won't know where that is (is it `/usr/local/bin/go`?, is it `/opt/go/bin`?, is it `$HOME/go1.5/bin`?, etc) so you should just leave setting a sane path to the user; just try and execute the command as `go` which will use `LookPath` and complain appropriately if not found. Limiting the path shouldn't be the job of a random program (unless *maybe* if it's a special case of a something setuid but that's a whole different can of worms).