# Call to systemd-coredump program using golang fails

Tags: linux, go, kubernetes, rhel

I am trying to call systemd-coredump program using golang in order to generate core dump but it somehow fails with `no such file or directory` error.
I am containerizing this code and deploying it as a pod in kubernetes.

Kubernetes has rhel version 7.6

Here is my code :

```
package main
import (
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

  coreProcessID := "<some process id>"
  partialCmd := "<arguments for core dump like %u %g %s %t %c %E>"
  coreCmd := "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump " + coreProcessID + " " + partialCmd
  fmt.Println("coreCmd is ", coreCmd)
        cmd := exec.Command(coreCmd)
        output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + string(output))
        } else {
            fmt.Println(string(output))
        }
}
```

I am getting this error : `fork/exec /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump 59009 %u %g %s %t %c %E: no such file or directory:` 
I even tried using `syscall.Exec` but it just exits the program without any error or output.

In Python it works fine using `os.system(core_cmd)` but somehow fails for golang.
How can I call systemd-coredump program using golang?

Retried with the below changes

```
cmd := exec.Command(coreCmd, coreProcessID, partialCmd)
        var out bytes.Buffer
        var stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        }
        fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
```

But it does not retrieve the output or generate core dump

Comment: The arguments must be passed individually to `os.Exec`. See the [exec docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to execute go file using os/exec package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451697/not-able-to-execute-go-file-using-os-exec-package)

Comment: I have performed it separately and exec.Command("sh", "-c", coreCmd) and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Testing again, will update in few minutes

Comment: I have modified the code with the suggestion in the link but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) what does `err` show, 2) if `partialCmd` contains multiple arguments, you still need to split them up.

Comment: `err` doesn't display anything and `partialCmd` can contain multiple argument as string and I have tested it for other commands and it works fine but not in this case.

Comment: Then please show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Including runnable code as is and full output.

Comment: The code which is provide is enough to reproduce it along with the commends. If you want platform details then :
Kubernetes : 1.17v
RHEL: 7.6
Golang: 1.14.1

Answer (score 0):

your original example works to some extent if re imagined like this

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    coreProcessID := os.Args[1]
    partialCmd := "%u %g %s %t %c %E"
    coreCmdArgs := coreProcessID + " " + partialCmd
    fmt.Println("coreCmdArgs are ", coreCmdArgs)
    coreCmdArgsAsSlice := strings.Split(" ", coreCmdArgs)
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump", coreCmdArgsAsSlice...)
    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + string(output))
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(output))
    }
}
```

the above on my system gives this error, which is presumably due to the way that systemd-coredump works

```
coreCmdArgs are  885 %u %g %s %t %c %E
exit status 1: Not enough arguments passed by the kernel (1, expected 6).
```